Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus two lines
I have this exercise (I don't know if it is taken from a book):

Caclulate the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3-(D_1 \cup D_2)$ where $D_{i \in \{1,2\} }$ are (straight) lines.

I consider three cases when the lines intersect, when they are parallel, and when they are skew lines
When they are parallel, I think of it, by homotopy as the wedge sum of two balls each minus a line, each homotopic to a 2-sphere minus two points, so the fundamental group in this case is $\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} $ (free group of two generators) by Van Kampen theorem or by the fact that the 2-sphere minus two points is homotopic to the plane minus a point.
I think I have the same result considering skew lines, when it comes to the case when they interesect, I am not sure, but I think of it as the 2-sphere minus four points, when deforming the lines inside the ball into a hole, which gives me $ \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} $
Is this correct?

Your intuition for two intersecting lines is correct. In fact you can give an explicit deformation retraction. Wlog, assume the two lines intersects at the origin, then you can show that the map $x\mapsto x/|x|$ gives the desired homotopy inverse to the inclusion of a 2-sphere minus 4 points.

This seems right to me! Note that topologically there's no distinction between parallel and skew lines (the second line can be rotated via an ambient homeomorphism to be parallel to the first).

@Kevin.S I see, thank you!!

You forgot the case where they are equal.

@GregMartin I thought that I will get different homotopies, but yes when I do the wedge sum, it is the same case. Thank you!

@psl2Z Yes, thank you! It is $\mathbb{Z}$ because it is homotopic to the 2-sphere minus two points.

The case of intersecting lines also deformation retracts to two pair of pants glued together like an "X".

@psl2Z I've never encountered this surface, but I see how that works, so we can apply Van Kampen theorem
